# If there is two thread calling different methods in objective c, how can avoid that the number will mess up?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

For example here is the .m:

```
-(void)counterPlusOne
{
  [_counter plusOne];
}

-(void)counterMinusOne
{
 [_counter minusOne];
}
```

There two methods may be called together, or one being called, another will be called as well. For example, if the userCallcountPlusOne, the `_counter`'s `plusOne` method, may be a lots of thing first. But while the calculating in `counterPlusOne`, the `counterMinusOne` may also being called. So, if these two thing go together, the `_counter`'s valuables may be messed up. How can I avoid that? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do the network activity indicator? Am I right?

Comment: _counter needs to be thread safe, there are some possibilities to achieve that. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html for a lot of tipps

Comment: Look at `OSAtomic...` functions to avoid `@synchronized`, locks, etc. To see all options, just run `man atomic` in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

try use `@synchronized` if you can't find better solution, because lock in code is bad in definition

```
-(void)counterPlusOne
{
    @synchronized(_counter)
    {
        [_counter plusOne];
    }
}

-(void)counterMinusOne
{
    @synchronized(_counter)
    {
        [_counter minusOne];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @`synchronized` mentioned by @sage444.

You can also use `NSRecursiveLock`:

```
@property (retain) NSRecursiveLock *accessLock;

- (id)init{
   self = [super init];
   [self setAccessLock:[[NSRecursiveLock alloc] init]];
   return self;
}

-(void)counterPlusOne
{
   [[self accessLock] lock];
   [_counter plusOne];
   [[self accessLock] unlock];
}

-(void)counterMinusOne{
    [[self accessLock] lock];
    [_counter minusOne];
    [[self accessLock] unlock];
}
```

And this method used frequently in `ASIHTTPRequest` source.